# How can I make Headset Microphone work on an Ubuntu 20.04 - Xiaomi laptop?

Tags: 20.04, sound, headset

I purchased a Xiaomi Mi Notebook Air 13.3 Laptop with Windows pre-installed. and installed Ubuntu on it. For most part, everything works Okay. But getting the headset mic to work has been difficult. On 20.04, the headset shows up under output device, not under input device.

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC255
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

I couldn't find anything for Xiaomi/Mi at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html

Any suggestions?
I am connecting the headset via a 3.5 mm jack and it does show up under output devices. Yes, I would like to get my Jabra 75t bluetooth also to get working. I tried pipewire for t hat. It worked, but since it was only mono, I stopped. As of now, it is the 3.5 mm jack-based headset that I am trying to get working.

Comment: How is the headset attached to the computer? 3.5 jack, Bluetooth, USB?

Comment: Added headset info - 3.5 mm jack.

Comment: I am going to make an educated guess as this same question came up just a few days ago. The headset only has one jack to plug in. It was intended for a phone not a computer.  Therefore it is doing what it should do. You plug into sound output on the computer you get sound. You plug into input on the computer the mic works. Personally I would use another headset that has 2 jacks or better still USB. It has been suggested but I have not tried to use a device to make the one jack into 2 and plug into both the input and the output.

Comment: The Bluetooth is a separate question. Search the site many answers there.

Comment: The laptop has only one 3.5 jack slot.

Comment: Then you need to use USB I would think. Ask the company who made the laptop how you get in and out from one jack.

Comment: Interesting idea. If I get a 3.5 to Type C adaptor and plug it into a USB port on the laptop, is it likely to accept is as audio in/out? I have an HDMI monitor connected and am able to direct the audio o/p there.

Comment: All I can say is try.

Comment: I purchased a 3.5 mm jack to USB C adaptor with sound card and bingo! It cost me only $7. I was thinking about buying a new laptop because of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I am  sure this is not a hardware limitation, as it works fine in windows. But the 3.5 to usb adapter seems like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, this was resolved (based on previous comment suggestions):

> I purchased a 3.5 mm jack to USB C adaptor with sound card and bingo! It cost me only $7. I was thinking about buying a new laptop because of this problem.

Posting as a community-wiki answer to improve the visibility.